# Simple select query not working with vb.net while delete query works fine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am writing a simple SQL Server query operation through vb.net application. I am having some strange problems.

This line is giving error:

```vb
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

This is giving me error **"Invalid column name `abhishek`**." Here `abhishek` is the data I am providing in `TextBox1.Text`. I am not able to think of any mistake by my side as this is a simple query. I am able to run other queries, like delete queries, on same table in a different form, so its not a database problem.

Any clue what's going wrong?

`reginfo` is the table name. `name` is one of the fields.

My complete code is below:

```vb
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form9
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from reginfo where name=" + (TextBox1.Text) + ""
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()    '<<< This line is creating problem
        If dr.Read() Then
            TextBox2.Text = dr(0).ToString()
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form8_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ABHISHEK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=locserver;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

if the name field is a text field then you need to enclose your textbox in single quotes, but this is bad advice to give. The only good approach to this kind of situations is through a parameterized query

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "select * from reginfo where name=@name"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  TextBox1.Text)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Also, do not keep global objects like a connection or a command. It is always a good practice to instantiate a connection as late as possible and close it as soon as possible, better inside a Using block

```vb
Using con = New SqlConnection(...connection string here....)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from reginfo where name=@name", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  TextBox1.Text)
        Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            '.... do you reading
        End Using
    End Using

End Using
```

In this way the connection is kept open for the minimum time possible and, also in case of exceptions is closed and disposed appropriately.

Comment: In VB.NET you can combine multiple usings together into a single declaration with a comma.  Otherwise each using statement should probably have it's own level of indentation.